# Can I reverse a registry setting, "DelegateExecute"=-, recommended in a previous post

Tags: windows-registry

I provided your advice on a post (below) for a user that was having trouble with hyperlinks in Windows 8 IE 10 and it did not fix his problem. He now wants me to tell him how to put it back the way it was and I do not know how. He did not make a backup of his registry as recommendded. If it is not too much trouble could you please tell me how to reverse this registry update if it is possible? If it is not possible could you please let me know what effect if any this upodate will have on his computer?

> Copy and Paste the following:
>
> ```
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.HTTP\shell\open\command]
> "DelegateExecute"=-
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.HTTPS\shell\open\command]
> "DelegateExecute"=-
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Extracted from Windows 7, should work on Windows 8 too:

```
 Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

 [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.HTTP\shell\open\command]
 "DelegateExecute"="{17FE9752-0B5A-4665-84CD-569794602F5C}"

 [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.HTTPS\shell\open\command]
 "DelegateExecute"="{17FE9752-0B5A-4665-84CD-569794602F5C}"
```

The procedure is the same: save it as a .reg file and double-click.

Comment: and Windows 10 Fwiw